# Top Bar not aligning in Foundation 6

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Foundation 6 and is experimenting with the example.  My question is why "Site Title" not aligning with the rest of the top-bar, it is further a little on top.

```
<div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-title">
          <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
            <span class="menu-icon dark" data-toggle></span>
          </span>
          <strong>Site Title</strong>
        </div>
        <div id="responsive-menu">
          <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
              <li>
                <a href="#">One</a>
                <ul class="menu vertical">
                  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
              <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It looks to be a padding or margin issue, But cannot tell with out the CSS can you please post.

Comment: please see https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.top-bar-title {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

fixed it.

Comment: added the margin top? nice. Sorry I didnt get back sooner.

Comment: no problem, thanks you gave me idea about margin top.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping it like this works

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="menu-text"><strong>Site Title</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

F6's .top-bar-title is documented on zurb but is not a class in top-bar.scss; seems like an oversight.